# Is there a 2D game engine for an RPG game where I can program in Java?

Tags: java, game-development

I'm very new to java and for my high school course assignment I need to make an RPG game with a story. The game has to have sound effects, combat system, generally like how Undertale is.

The biggest challenge is that I have to program it in Java. Not only am I new and I don't know how to do graphics in java, but there are also no game engines like Gamemaker Studio that uses java. They're all just libraries.

Comment: I think you're biting off far more than you can chew by trying to write an Undertale-like RPG. You say you're very new to Java and you're in high school, and if you do this as a class project, then you have little time. Try choosing a much more modest project. Your teacher should be able to advise you as to what's realistic.